# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown not working (Not Responsive) on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a dropdown to my website but it is not working properly on mobile devices when the nav bar is collapsed. When I click on dropdown it closes the navbar instead of showing the items under the dropdown.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Name</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Games <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/Spikes" target="_blank">Avoid The Spikes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/SpaceShooter" target="_blank">Space Shooter</a></li>
                        <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>-->
                        <!--<li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>-->
                        <!--<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>-->
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I think it has something to do with the ID `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`